# Why can I not combine a LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE clause in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running into a syntax error with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from accounts
WHERE accounts.level = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications ON verifications.account_id = accounts.id
WHERE verifications.account_id IS NULL;
```

Here is a second variation that I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications ON verifications.account_id = accounts.id
WHERE verifications.account_id IS NULL
WHERE accounts.level = 0;
```

What I want to do is I want to select `accounts` that do not have an associated `verifications` object and whose level is equal only to 0. In my mind this query makes sense to me but obviously not. What could I be doing wrong here? Additionally, as a bonus, I intend to add more `LEFT OUTER JOINS` statements to filter the accounts table with the combined associations. For this scenario would a `UNION` statement be needed to aggregate the results or can I just pile on the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: WHERE comes last after all the JOINs and you don`t repeat it ,insted you use AND if you have 2 or more conditions

Comment: Take baby steps. First learn INNER JOIN, and then add WHERE, and later consider LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to do is I want to select accounts that do not have an associated verifications object and whose level is equal only to 0.

A more canonical way to do that is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from accounts
WHERE accounts.level = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT NULL 
   FROM verifications 
   WHERE verifications.account_id = accounts.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need one WHERE statement, if you need multiple clauses then you need to use the operators AND or OR;

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN verifications 
    ON verifications.account_id = accounts.id
WHERE verifications.account_id IS NULL
    AND accounts.level = 0;
```